# How do I preserve newline character in Spring while sending data through a JSP form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a *JSP* that contains a `textarea`:

```html
<label for="personalMessage">
  <fmt:message key="text.createapersonalmessage" /> 
  <a class="helpIcon" 
     title="<fmt:message key="description.receiptmessage" />" 
     href="javascript:;">  
    <img src="resources/images/helpIcon.png" 
         width="16" 
         height="16" 
         border="0" 
         align="bottom">
  </a>
</label>
<fmt:message key="text.createapersonalmessage" var="createapersonalmessage">
</fmt:message>
<form:textarea path="personalMessage" maxlength="140" rows="3" cols="20" 
placeholder="${createapersonalmessage}" class="hasPlaceholder" />
```

The `textarea` with path *personalMessage* may contain newline characters or tab characters. I need to retain the formatting when contents are sent back to my controller. Right now I see that all the newline/tabs are being converted to whitespaces by *Spring* once the submit button is hit.

```html
<input type="submit" 
       name="" 
       value="<fmt:message key="text.savesettings"/>" 
       id="" 
       class="css3button" style="width:auto;" />
```

Is it possible to retain the newline/tab characters? I have tried using /n , /r/n, 
, &#10 and &#13 and whitespace-pre in my css but nothing seems to work.

Edit: I am using a Spring MVC. So upon hitting submit my setters are called by spring and the data sent to the setter has all newline/tabs replaced by whitespaces. I do not have a way to distinguish between desired whitespaces and "converted" whitespaces.

Comment: As far as I know, this behavior si of standars, an the textarea will split everything back once submitted. You may need to do it using JavaScript.

Comment: @tmarwen No, you can submit newlines in a textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently all I needed is to set

```
wrap = "physical"
```

for my textArea.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring form looks correct and I guess Spring is handling your data correctly as well.

You need to replace your newlines '\n' with an HTML

```
<br/>
```

tag when outputting the data.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? right now I am trying to do this :    var myTextareaVal = $('#personalMessage').value;
 var myLineBreak = myTextareaVal.replaceAll(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    $('#personalMessage').value = myLineBreak;    not sure if it correct

Comment: Could you include the code (JSP) where you output the personal message?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `htmlEscape="false"` to your `<form:textarea>` definition should work...

This will avoid replacing characters thar are not valid in HTML, like new lines and tabs, among others.

Comment: <form:textarea path="personalMessage" maxlength="140" rows="3" cols="20" htmlEscape="false" placeholder="${createapersonalmessage}" class="hasPlaceholder"   did not work. Is this the correct way to do it? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Not what the OP was asking for. Setting `htmlEscape` to false will only escape special HTML entities (like '<' for instance), so that you start seeing `<br>` text on your page. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape-java.lang.String-